# Share member between two objects

Tags: c++

I have two classes, A and B like this :

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int i)
    {
        this->i = i;
    }
private:
    int i;
};

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        i = 0;
        a = new A(i);
        i++;
        // i = 1
        // a->i must be 1
    }

private:
    A* a;
    int i;
};
```

I tri to share a member between the two objects.
I want when i is modified in B, i have to be modified in A.
How can I doing something like that ? It is possible by reference ?
I hope I was clear.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible by reference, but then you run into scoping issues.

You can also have a `std::shared_ptr` to share variables between classes.

Answer (score 1):

Without creating a cyclic dependency you need a third object (you can use the address of something if you want) that is shared/known to both classes.

While I prefer reference to pointers in many cases I tend to avoid references because they are not necessarily good candidates for sharing data when the life-time of the shared object is hard to decide over. A `std::shared_ptr` might be a good fit.

Though, it might also be as simple as

```
int x;
A* a = new A(&x);
B* b = new B(&x);
```

However, in this example a reference is more appropriate but given that the scope here doesn't say anything about the life-time of `a` and `b` I'd go with all heap and a `shared_ptr` to not stumble on the problem of *who will delete the shared memory?*...

```
#include <memory>
auto x = std::make_shared<int>(0);
A* a = new A(x);
B* b = new B(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Luchian said, you need to be careful of scope and the lifetime of the variable that you're referencing.  In your example as long as B never outlives A you would be fine.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int &i) : m_i(i)
    {
    }
private:
    int &m_i;
};

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        i = 0;
        a = new A(i);
        i++;
        // i = 1
        // a->i must be 1
    }

private:
    A* a;
    int i;
};
```